# How can I open games I downloaded?

Tags: command-line, games, paths

Every time I download a game from the terminal I can't open it.

Example 1:

```
$ sudo apt-get install 0ad
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0ad is already the newest version (0.0.22-3.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-atomic1.62.0 libboost-chrono1.62.0 libboost-program-options1.62.0
  libboost-serialization1.62.0 libboost-test1.62.0 libboost-timer1.62.0
  libcaribou-gtk-module libcaribou-gtk3-module libcgal12 libevent-2.0-5
  libgom-1.0-common libqcustomplot1.3 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libsfcgal1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
```

Now when I try to launch O A.D.:

```
0ad
bash: 0ad: command not found
```

Example 2:

```
sudo apt-get install nsnake
```

same thing...

Now time to run it.

```
nsnake  
bash: nsnake: command not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$/usr/games/nsnake and /usr/local/games/nsnake
```

Check your PATH variable. Does it include */usr/games and /usr/local/games*?

```
echo $PATH
```

If not, edit .profile to include

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: i get this:    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: @Iron Moods, On which command? the "/usr/games/nsnake"? or the "echo $PATH"?

Comment: nevermind i got it working when i type /usr/games/(gamename)   Thanks!

Comment: @Iron Moods, . the games directory is not in your path.  Neither is "/usr/local/games". Try "/usr/local/games/nsnake" but in any case to add these to your .profile file as in "PATH=$PATH:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Answer (score 0):

Normally $PATH variable contains two games folders - `/usr/games` and `/usr/local/games`:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

On old-style desktops such as GNOME FlashBack or MATE DE exists *Applications* menu with *Games* category. Game with GUI may be launched from it.

If you need to know from which executable GUI game is started, you can view its `.desktop` file (like `.lnk` in MS Windows) and find its executable here.

I present example here for `aisleriot` package with GNOME card games:

```
grep -r Exec $(dpkg -L aisleriot | grep .desktop)
```

here:

- `dpkg -L aisleriot` - lists files from `aisleriot` package
- `|` - pipes output from left command to right command
- `grep .desktop` - finds all `*.desktop` files in the output of `dpkg` command
- `grep -r Exec` - finds and prints `Exec` lines from all found `*.desktop` files

On my system this command outputs the following:

```
Exec=/usr/games/sol
```

so `aisleriot` package has only one `*.desktop` file, which contains `Exec=/usr/games/sol` line. If one want to launch `aisleriot` game from terminal he should launch it with `sol` command (locate in `/usr/games/`, which is normally in `$PATH`).